# regex getting url link

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to extract the link I am getting from a curl command. Curl command throws back of type string.

```
{"success":true,"key":"Syv77d","link":"https://file.io/Syv77d","expiry":"14 days"}
```

In my below code this gets `https://file.io/Syv77d","expiry":"14 days"}`
    `link = re.search('https://.*$',fileIO)`

What I wanted was just `https://file.io/Syv77d`

The link would vary so i would need the url without the double-qoutes. I think I am missing something in my regex.

Comment: Use a JSON parser? Just get `json.loads(x)["link"]` where `x` is the JSON

Comment: It appears the response is in [JSON](https://json.org/) format. You may consider using Python's `json` module instead of manually parsing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the string object to a JSON object.

**Ex:**

```
import json
jData = json.loads('{"success":true,"key":"Syv77d","link":"https://file.io/Syv77d","expiry":"14 days"}')
jData["link"]
```

Comment: yes i have done exactly like this. thanks as well

Comment: You are welcome. Please accept ans if it solved your problem. Thanks